# Finding the inverse of an element in $\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{3}})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, inverse

I did find the following post: [Finding a representation of the inverse as linear combination](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4662957/finding-a-representation-of-the-inverse-as-linear-combination)

It is about the question how to calculate $(7+2^{\frac{2}{3}})^{-1} \in \mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{3}})$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$- linear combination of $\{1,2^{\frac{1}{3}},2^{\frac{2}{3}}\}$.

The below answer did suggest that one writes

$1=(7+2^{\frac{2}{3}})^{-1} (7+2^{\frac{2}{3}})=(\lambda_1+\lambda_22^{\frac{1}{3}}+\lambda_3 2^{\frac{2}{3}})(7+2^{\frac{2}{3}})$

I did try this approach but couldn't solve it correctly.
Here is what I did:

$1=(7+2^{\frac{2}{3}})^{-1} (7+2^{\frac{2}{3}})=(\lambda_1+\lambda_2 2^{\frac{1}{3}}+\lambda_3 2^{\frac{2}{3}})(7+2^{\frac{2}{3}})$

$(\lambda_1+\lambda_22^{\frac{1}{3}}+\lambda_3 2^{\frac{2}{3}})(7+2^{\frac{2}{3}})=7\lambda_1+7 \lambda_2 2^{\frac{1}{3}}+7 \lambda_3 2^{\frac{2}{3}}+ \lambda_1 2^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \lambda_2+2 \lambda_3 2^{\frac{1}{3}}$

$=(7\lambda_1+2\lambda_2)+2^{\frac{1}{3}}(\lambda_2+2\lambda_3)+2^{\frac{2}{3}}(7\lambda_3+\lambda_1)$

Thus we have
$\;1=(7\lambda_1+2\lambda_2)+2^{\frac{1}{3}}(\lambda_2+2\lambda_3)+2^{\frac{2}{3}}(7\lambda_3+\lambda_1)$

and we get the system

$7\lambda_1+2\lambda_2=1$

$\lambda_2+2\lambda_3=0$

$\lambda_1+7\lambda_3=0$

Solving it (by hand and by Wolframalpha:
[Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=7%CE%BB_1%2B2%CE%BB_2%3D1%5C%2844%29%CE%BB_2%2B2%CE%BB_3%3D0%5C%2844%29%CE%BB_1%2B7%CE%BB_3%3D0) )
I get

$\lambda_1=\frac{7}{53}$

$\lambda_2=\frac{2}{53}$

$\lambda_3=-\frac{1}{53}$

Now checking the calculation I get that it is wrong:
[Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=%5C%2840%29Divide%5B7%2C53%5D%2BDivide%5B2%2C53%5DPower%5B2%2CDivide%5B1%2C3%5D%5D-Divide%5B1%2C53%5DPower%5B2%2CDivide%5B2%2C3%5D%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%297%2BPower%5B2%2CDivide%5B1%2C3%5D%5D%5C%2841%29) )

Question: Where is my mistake? I don't really understand what went wrong. Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where is my mistake?

It should be $\color{red}7\lambda_2+2\lambda_3=0$, so $\lambda_1=\dfrac{49}{347}, \lambda_2=\dfrac2{347},$ and $\lambda_3=-\dfrac7{347}$.

Comment: Big thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Write out the product
$$
\begin{align}
1
&=\left(7+2^{2/3}\right)\left(a+b2^{1/3}+c2^{2/3}\right)\\
&=(7a+2b)+(7b+2c)2^{1/3}+(a+7c)2^{2/3}
\end{align}
$$
which leads to the matrix equation
$$
\begin{bmatrix}7&2&0\\0&7&2\\1&0&7\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
which gives the solution
$$
\frac{49}{347}+\frac2{347}2^{1/3}-\frac7{347}2^{2/3}
$$
The second equation (coefficient of $2^{1/3}$) seems to be where your mistake is